# I am making a basic terminal style OS in 16 bit NASM and I cant seem to load into sector two

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, bios

I have been working on an operating system in NASM 16 bits and the bootloader functions fine, but when it tries to load stage two it just stops, here's what I have.

```
[bits 16]           ; tell assembler that working in real mode(16 bit mode)
[org 0x7c00]        ; organize from 0x7C00 memory location where BIOS will load us
%define cr 0xd
%define lf 0xa

start:              ; start label from where our code starts


    xor ax,ax           ; set ax register to 0
    mov ds,ax           ; set data segment(ds) to 0
    mov es,ax           ; set extra segment(es) to 0
    mov bx,0x8000
    ;clear screen
    mov ah, 00h
    mov al, 2
    int 10h
    ;reset cursor
    mov ah, 02h
    mov bh, 00h
    mov dh, 00h
    mov dl, 00h
    int 10h
    ;start kernl
    mov si, intro_os
    ; load second sector into memory
    mov ah, 0x02                    ; load second stage to memory
    mov al, 1                       ; numbers of sectors to read into memory
    mov dl, 0x80                    ; sector read from fixed/usb disk
    mov ch, 0                       ; cylinder number
    mov dh, 0                       ; head number
    mov cl, 2                       ; sector number
    mov bx, _OS_Stage_2             ; load into es:bx segment :offset of buffer
    int 0x13                        ; disk I/O interrupt
    call print_str
    mov si, loading
    call print_str
    jmp _OS_Stage_2                 ; jump to second stage
    ;Functions here
    print_str:
    mov ah, 0xE
    .repeat:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je .done
    int 10h
    jmp .repeat
    .done:
    ret
    read_inp:
    .repeat:
    mov ah, 00h
    int 16h
    cmp al, 0x1c
    je .done
    mov bx, [input_idx]
    mov [input+bx], al
    inc byte [input_idx]
    mov ah, 0xE
    int 10h
    jmp .repeat
    .done:
    mov byte [input_idx], 0
    ret
    ;end functions
    ;vars and strings
    intro_os db 'ProtOS VERSION:ALPHA-001, written by Julian Ratcliffe.',cr,lf,0
    loading db 'Please wait, we are loading the operating system...',cr,lf,0
    kern_mn db cr,lf,'<ProtOS_V_A001>---$ ',0
    input times 100 db 0
    input_idx db 0
    ;end vars and strings
    times ((0x200 - 2) - ($ - $$)) db 0x00
    dw 0xAA55  
    _OS_Stage_2:
    mov ah, 00h
    mov al, 02h
    int 10h
    
    mov si, intro_os
    call print_str
    mov si, kern_mn
    call print_str
    call read_inp
    ; add how much memory we need
    times (1024 - ($-$$)) db 0x00
```

it prints the `intro_os` and `loading` strings but stops when it tries `jmp _OS_Stage_2`
I don't understand why it's not loading into part two, please tell me anything I can fix, I'm still pretty new to NASM.
Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that is the actual code you are using? It can not print the strings since that is already in the second sector (everything after the `dw 0xAA55 ` is).

Comment: Fixed it, sorry I am still new to this OS development thing.

Comment: So it works now, right? It does here.

Comment: It still doesn't load into pt2.

Comment: Make sure you really have drive 0x80. Better yet, store the value that the BIOS gave you initially (in `dl`). Also how are you creating the disk and how do you run it?

Comment: `nasm -f bin -o ProtOS.bin protos.asm` for the disk file, and `qemu-system-i386 -L "C:\Program Files\qemu" -fda ProtOS.bin` to simulate a BIOS env

Comment: You realize `fda` is a floppy, right? So your comment `sector read from fixed/usb disk` obviously contradicts that. As I said, use the original value in `dl` or for a floppy use `0x00` or use `-hda`.

Comment: _facepalm_ Man I really need to think more.